# Retrieving Data from Aspentech IP21 using pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to read data from Aspench IP21 database (windows 10). I have used same ODBC driver from excel and it works without any issue. But when I try to test pyodbc to do same I get following error message:

```
import pypyodbc
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={AspenTech SQLplus};HOST=10.10.10.10;PORT=10014")
```

> Error: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to
> system error  126: The specified module could not be found. (AspenTech
> SQLplus, C:\Windows\System32\ip21odbc.dll).')

DLL file is on that location, it is double checked.

Tested also with pyodbc to excel and it works.

Any hints to continue the troubleshooting or solve the issue ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: Yes, If I remember correctly I added  os.add_dll_directory(path) to point that folder where dll is stored. I don't have a code right now so I cannot check it. But that was the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pypyodbc
driver = 'AspenTech SQLplus'
host = 'IP21Server'
port = 10014
conn = pyodbc.connect(f"DRIVER={driver}; HOST={host}; PORT={port}")
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Regarding the ODBC connection it's worth to have a look in AspenTech's knowledgebase - eg article 65086 "Using Aspen SQLplus ODBC driver with Python".
Also online help of SQLplus gives helpful additional information on ODBC connections: Search for "DSN-less Connections".